# Which value is of higher precedence, updatePeriodMillis or the value associated with the Alarm?

Tags: android, android-widget, anti-patterns

I understand that the parameter `updatePeriodMillis` determines how often an app `widget` gets updated according to the specification in the `widgetproviderinfo.xml` present in /res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure="com.example.appwidget.ConfigurationActivity"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/layout_appwidget_large"
    android:minHeight="115dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000" ><!-- 30mins -->
</appwidget-provider>
```

This approach has a drawback in that it updates the `widget` by waking up the phone at the designated interval if the phone is sleeping. So the issue is about battery consumption 
which is a major issue if the interval is very small.

If, however, you need to update more frequently and/or you do not need to update while the device is asleep, then you can instead perform updates based on an alarm that will
not wake the device. To do so, set an alarm with an `Intent` that your `AppWidgetProvider` receives, using the `AlarmManager`. Set the alarm type to either
ELAPSED_REALTIME or RTC, which will only deliver the alarm when the device is awake. Then set `updatePeriodMillis` to zero ("0"). to 
The code would look something like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pending);
long interval = 1000*60;
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pending);
```

So my question is as follows:
Let's say the AlarmManager is used to carry out the update. Additionally, if in the widgetproviderinfo.xml, updatePeriodMillis is **NOT** set to 0, then 
Which value will take the precedence? The value specified as part of the Alarm or updatePeriodMillis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of them will trigger an `onUpdate()` call.

If you set an alarm at 20 minutes and your `updatePeriodMillis` to 30 minutes.

Then u place your `widget` on the home screen. After 20 minutes, the alarm will trigger an `onUpdate` to be called (can be any other function of your choosing actually). Then 10 minutes later (in total, 30 mins since widget placed on screen), `updatePeriodMillis` will trigger an `onUpdate()`. Then 10 minutes later (40mins since widget placed on screen), the alarm will trigger another `onUpdate()`. And finally 20 minutes later (60mins since widget placed on screen) `updatePeriodMillis` will trigger another `onUpdate()`.

Answer (score 1):

From android DOC:
Note: Updates requested with updatePeriodMillis will not be delivered more than once every 30 minutes.
[enter link description here][1]
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis

so basically if you set updatePeriodMillis to less than 1800000, android wouldn't call your onUpdate method until 30min passeed

Comment: Your explanation is unclear. Do you mean to say that if updatePeriodMillis is present and is configured to less than 1800000, Android will consider 1800000 as a default value?(This would be correct if an Alarm is NOT configured)

If updatePeriodMillis < 1800000 and an Alarm is configured, then which would take precedence? Would it depend on which value is larger?  
Additionally, and more importantly what is the expected behavior when updatePeriodMillis is configured to a value greater than 1800000 and also an Alarm has been configured?
Could you please address all the cases?